# SQL replace NULL by column type dependant default value as fast as possible

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, performance

I have a big SQL table (60 columns, 2 million rows). My customer wants to import it into Excel. NULL values must be replaced by a column type dependant default value ('1900-01-01 00:00:00', '', 0, O.Of, ...).

Currently, it is done by updating each column individually and it takes 40-50% of the time of the whole analytic query (!). What is the fastest way to do this ?

Comment: You could use `ISNULL` or `COLLESCE` in the `SELECT` query column list rather than updating data after the fact.

Comment: How are you currently doing it?

Comment: Tried again, and the ISNULL or COALESCE based query is much faster. 0% of global duration ! Previous method was to use 60 UPDATE

Comment: And the 60 UPDATE were taking 40-50% of global query duration.

Comment: I confirm: issue solved. Thx very much !

Comment: In fact, the reason SELECT ISNULL ... is faster then one UPDATE per column is because updating most rows of a table requires logging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a query like

```
SELECT
    ISNULL(Field1, '') AS Field1,                      -- string column
    ISNULL(Field2, '1900-01-01 00:00:00') AS Field2,   -- date column
    ISNULL(Field3, 0) AS Field3,                       -- int column
    (etc)
```

Comment: this datetime format is not language neutral, best always use a language neutral datetime format, see [this](https://karaszi.com/the-ultimate-guide-to-the-datetime-datatypes)

Comment: Thx Michael, it worked ! It executes in no time now !